# Wrong version of System.Runtime being packaged

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-cloud-services

We have written a service to be deployed to Azure.  This consists of a DLL with a "Worker Role" class, and an Azure Cloud Service project, as shown below:
[image]

The build steps are:

1. Build the ccproj in "Release" configuration.
2. Run NuGet "spec", then "pack" to get a .nupkg file
3. Deploy the .nupkg file to the Azure Cloud Service

This has been working fine for a while, until we upgraded to .NET 4.6.2 and also upgraded several other references, including System.Runtime (now v4.3.1).  Now, despite the fact that we have (probably unnecessarily) added a NuGet reference to *every single* project in the solution, pointing to System.Runtime 4.3.1, the version of System.Runtime.dll that gets deployed is an older version, resulting in DLL hell on the service, which then fails to run.  If we manually copy over the correct version of System.Runtime.dll, then everything works again.

Where is this incorrect version of System.Runtime coming from?  And how do we convince the offending software/hardware to use the correct version?

**UPDATE:** Trail is getting warmer.  On my development machine, the `bin` folder of the EventWorker project contains the correct version of System.Runtime.dll.  But... the `EventProcessor\obj\debug\EventWorker` folder contains the old version!  I deleted the `obj` folder and recompiled the project - and the old version of the DLL appears again.

Where is it coming from, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it, but I'm not sure why this worked.  I *removed* the NuGet reference to `System.Runtime` from the `EventWorker` project.  And now the `EventProcessorRole` is using the correct version of the DLL.

I'll mark this as the answer in the meantime, but if anyone can provide an explanation for this behavior, I'll give you answer credit...

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea in terms of hunting down the offending DLL.  Have you any dependent DLL's which could be using the wrong version?  Also, when run locally does it give you the dll conflict warning in the errors window, allowing you to identify where?  Take a look at your config file and see if you have a reference to the DLL version in the redirects section, update it or create a new one to point at the latest version.

Comment: There are no conflict messages at compile time, only at runtime when deployed to Azure.  But now I've found some new information - please see update to my question.

Comment: On my latter point, Is there a reference to it in the redirects section of your app.config in the worker?  If that states a version, then it doesn't matter what you add and it will work as you have the old version locally.   Hence why it doesn't work in the cloud.

Comment: `app.config` has : `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />`

Comment: That is referring to the new version - but the old version is being deployed, hence the problem.

Comment: It isn't, it's referring to upto 4.1.1 not 4.3.1

Comment: Oho.  But that is the alteration that was automatically made to my `app.config` and `web.config` files when I added the NuGet reference to System.Runtime 4.3.1.  Are you sure the version numbers here are meant to match?  (I often get confused by the inconsistency in version numbering of these packages...)

Comment: Also, remember that the service works when I manually copy over the 4.3.1 DLL (which, incidentally, shows file version number 4.6.24702.1).  And I didn't edit the `app.config` file (which is pointing at version 4.1.1.0)

Comment: To prove a point, you have already removed all references to the old version, just comment out this redirect section and build it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127989/discussion-between-steve-newton-and-shaul-behr).